# How to Update Salesforce Custom Object through AmpScript in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, custom-object

We have an Email that has a CTA Button and upon clicking the CTA Button the response should be captured in MC and a field in Salesforce Custom Object should get updated. My code is working fine in updating DE but not updating the CRM object.
I passed 2 ID's because we have both leads and contacts receiving same email.

Code in Email

```
%%[
    set @Id = AttributeValue("Id")
    set @Email = AttributeValue("Email")
    set @AccountId = RequestParameter("Account_Id")


    set @CTA_Url = CloudPagesURL("112", "Id", @Id,"Account_Id",@AccountId, "Email", @Email)                                          
]%%
```

Code in Cloud Page

```
%%[ 
 
set @Email = RequestParameter("Email") 
set @Id= RequestParameter("id")
set @AccountId = RequestParameter("Account_Id")
set @rowsUpdated = UpsertDE( "ResponseDE",1,'Id',@Id, "Delivery_Status",'Delivered' ) 


set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject( 'Request__c',@AccountId, 'Status__c','Delivered', 'StoreStatus__c', 'Closed' )
 
 ]%%
```

DE is updating fine but not SF object

Note : The reason you see AcccountID in SF is we are using Person COntact ID and in our DE the field name is just ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` [function](https://ampscript.guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject/). You will see the description for the 2nd parameter is: "Record identifier to update" which means the record Id of the object.

So what you suppose to fill to this parameter is the record Id of `Request__c` custom object not the Contact Id or Lead Id.

First you would want to include the `Request__c` record Id in your send DE source so then you can:

1. Pass this "Request Id" parameter to your CTA URL in the Email part
2. Request parameter in your Cloudpage to get this "Request Id" value and use `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` to update the custom object record in Salesforce CRM

Comment: Thanks it worked.